# Mac .bash_profile.save How to make it run by itself / where to actually change paths

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, path, .bash-profile

trying to change my path for Ruby / SASS.

I have always used a file in my home called '.bash_profile.save'

In there I have the export paths which work fine but only when I run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile.save
```

After that the paths are correct. Is there a way to make it so that I don't have to run this everythime? Possibly a bash profile that is ran by default but I don't see a file for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Renaming it to .bash_profile might help.